# show that $d(X,x) = d([X],x)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

show that $d(X,x) = d([X],x)$ where $d(X,x) = \inf_{y \in X} \lambda (x,y)$ where $\lambda$ is a metric and $[X] = \{ x \in X : d(X,x) = 0 \}$

I have shown $d([X],x) \leq d(X,x)$ I am stuck proving the inequality the other way. I have tried by contradication i.e. assume $d([X],x) > d(X,x)$ but i can't find a contradiciton

Comment: What is $X$? Any metric space, or you have some more conditions?

Comment: no more conditions, just a metric space.

Comment: Is $[X]$ the same as the closure of $X$? I've normally seen that written as $\overline X$.

Comment: ^ yes it is, that's a definition.

Comment: I posted a way to prove it. You'll have to check the details, but it should work without too many problems.

Comment: The OP edited the question in a way that makes it impossible to understand. I reverted the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{x_n\}\subseteq[X]$ be a sequence such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda(x_n,x) = d([X],x).$$
As for every $n$ we have $d(X,x_n) = 0$, we have sequences $\{y^n_k\}_k\subseteq X$ such that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}y^n_k = x_n.$$
Consider the diagonal sequence $\{z_n = y^n_n\}\subseteq X$. We have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda(z_n,x) = d([X],x),$$
which implies $d(X,x)\le d([X],x)$.

Comment: Thanks, I had hoped it would be easier than this.

Comment: @maths I don't think it's really hard. You take a sequence converging to the infimum in $[X]$ and you would like to find out something about $X$. You notice that there's a sequence in $X$ converging to each point of $[X]$, so you take these. Then taking the diagonal sequence is pretty standard. Anyway, there might be a less convoluted way, only this one was the first that came up to my mind.