# show that $x \in A^o$ if and only if $d(A^c,x) > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

show that $x \in A^o \iff d(A^c,x) > 0$ where $d(A^c,x) = \inf_{y\in A^c} \lambda (x,y)$ where $\lambda$ is a metric and $(X,\lambda)$ is a metric space and $A^o$ is the set of interior points of A

I have tried to do the forward implication:

$x \in A^o \subset A \subset [A] = \{ x \in X : d(A,x) = 0 \}$ but then this means $d(A,x) = 0$ hence $d(A^c,x) > 0$ I am having troubles doing the reverse implication.

Comment: The OP edited the post in a way that makes it impossible to understand. Since this was done simultaneously on the other post by this user, this looks like a try to erase one's steps. I reverted the edit. OP: Don't do that again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $x\in A^{\circ}.$ Suppose that $d(A^c,x)=0.$ Then, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exist $y\in A^c$ such that $d(x,y)<\epsilon.$ But, since $x\in A^{\circ}$ there exists $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\subset A^{\circ}.$ So, if we consider $\epsilon=r$ we get a contradiction because

$$d(y,x)<r \implies y \in B(x,r) \subset A^{\circ} \implies y\in A^{\circ},$$ which is not possible because $y\in A^c.$

Now suppose that $d(A^c,x)>0.$ Then, there exist $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\cap A^c=\emptyset.$ That is, $B(x,r)\in A,$ which means, $x\in A^{\circ}.$

Comment: Hi - is my forward implication incorrect as yours differs. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: From $d(x,A)=0$ you can't say directly that  $d(x,A^c)>0.$ Think of $A=(-\infty,0)$ and $x=0$ in the real line.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that this question is perfectly equivalent to [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1621612/60713) (to which I already gave an answer).

Answer (score 0):

*Proof.* For the converse, we shall prove the contrapositive statement that $x \notin A^0 \implies d(A^c, x) \leq 0$. Suppose $x \notin A^0$. Note that the case where $x \in A^c$ is trivial. Suppose $x \in A$. Then $x$ is not an interior point of $A$. Then for all $\epsilon>0$, we have some $y \in A^c$ such that $y \in B_\lambda(x, \epsilon)$, giving us $d(A^c, x) \leq \lambda(x, y)<\epsilon$. It follows that $d(A^c, x) \leq 0$. $\square$

Anything I have called "trivial" takes a little bit of poking at the definition as to why. If you're stuck, shoot me a comment.

Hope that helps.